# Pandas DataFrame Conditional Criteria To Update Columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following:
DataFrame = new_project_column_test
Columns = ServiceName, Project_Col, Project_Name

The ServiceName column will be a mixed list of Technology Tools
Project_Col and Project_Name will be mixed with both of them having some names that contain the word 'project' in them (sometimes in the beginning, middle, and end), along with mixed random data.

The below examples are to be applied through each column (if that makes sense). Meaning, I am trying to make all the updates within the existing column Project_Col.

Here is some data that can be used.

**ServiceName**
SQL Datbase
Server
Virtual Network

**Project_Col**
the_project_center
happy_data_network
project_centric

**Project_Name**
big_data_splash
my_main_project
project_vulcan

**If column Project_Name contains 'project' and;
Column SeriveName is SQL Database, then;
update Project_Col with the value from column Project_Name**

`if (('project' in new_project_column_test['Project_Name'] and (new_project_column_test['ServiceName'] == 'SQL Database')): new_project_column_test['Project_Col'] = new_project_column_test['Project_Name']`

**If column Project_Name contains 'project' and;
Column Project_Col contains 'project', then;
update Project_Col with the value from column Project_Name**

`if (('project' in new_project_column_test['Project_Name']) and ('project' in new_project_column_test['Project_Col'])): new_project_column_test['Project_Col'] = new_project_column_test['Project_Name']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
import numpy as np
​
#for the sake of readability
df = new_project_column_test
​
m1 = (df['Project_Name'].str.contains('project')) & (df['ServiceName'].eq('SQL Database'))
m2 = (df['Project_Name'].str.contains('project')) & (df['Project_Col'].str.contains('project'))
​
df['Project_Col'] = np.where(m1|m2, df['Project_Name'], df['Project_Col'])
```

For more complex combinations, check out [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).​

Output :

```
print(df)

       ServiceName         Project_Col     Project_Name
0     SQL Database  the_project_center  big_data_splash
1           Server  happy_data_network  my_main_project
2  Virtual Network      project_vulcan   project_vulcan # <- project_vulcan is the new value in Project_Col
```

Comment: Thank you you so much for this feedback. Very humbled and appreciated for your time in addressing my inquiry and you providing feedback in layman terms. This really helps me to grasp the concept versus just getting the answer. I'm appreciative of you and others' who contribute to this forum.